# Difficulty Configuring JSON Authentication for Box from Java

Tags: java, json, netbeans-8, box

I'm working on a simple automated java program for using the box api and am trying to use json. I've borrowed the first part of the checkstyle sample code from the Github's repo example [SearchExamplesAsAppUser](https://github.com/box/box-java-sdk/blob/master/src/example/java/com/box/sdk/example/SearchExamplesAsAppUser.java), figuring it should work.

When I run it, I get a this error

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/bouncycastle/operator/OperatorCreationException

The problem seems to be stemming from the statement:

```
api = BoxDeveloperEditionAPIConnection.getAppUserConnection(USER_ID, boxConfig, accessTokenCache);
```

The Jars which I am using are (aside from commons, all  recommended by box):

```
bcpkix-jdk15on-1.52.jar
bcprov-jdk15on-1.52.jar
box-java-sdk-2.14.1.jar
jose4j-0.4.4.jar
minimal-json-0.9.1.jar
commons-codec-1.9.jar
commons-httpclient-3.1.jar
commons-logging-1.2.jar
```

I am using netbeans so all of the jars above are listed under the libraries to use fr compilation.

The code is as follows:

```
package boxapitest;

import com.box.sdk.BoxAPIConnection;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import com.box.sdk.BoxConfig;
import com.box.sdk.BoxDeveloperEditionAPIConnection;
import com.box.sdk.BoxItem;
import com.box.sdk.BoxMetadataFilter;
import com.box.sdk.BoxSearch;
import com.box.sdk.BoxSearchParameters;
import com.box.sdk.BoxUser;
import com.box.sdk.DateRange;
import com.box.sdk.IAccessTokenCache;
import com.box.sdk.InMemoryLRUAccessTokenCache;
import com.box.sdk.PartialCollection;
import com.box.sdk.SizeRange;

public final class BoxAPITest {
private static final String USER_ID = "***email address removed for privacy***";
private static final int MAX_DEPTH = 1;
private static final int MAX_CACHE_ENTRIES = 100;

private static BoxDeveloperEditionAPIConnection api;

/**
* @param args the command line arguments
* @throws java.io.IOException
*/
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
// Turn off logging to prevent polluting the output.
Logger.getLogger("com.box.sdk").setLevel(Level.SEVERE);

//It is a best practice to use an access token cache to prevent unneeded requests to Box for access tokens.
//For production applications it is recommended to use a distributed cache like Memcached or Redis, and to
//implement IAccessTokenCache to store and retrieve access tokens appropriately for your environment.
IAccessTokenCache accessTokenCache = new InMemoryLRUAccessTokenCache(MAX_CACHE_ENTRIES);

Reader reader;
reader = new FileReader("\\My Path\\file.json");
BoxConfig boxConfig = BoxConfig.readFrom(reader);

api = BoxDeveloperEditionAPIConnection.getAppUserConnection(USER_ID, boxConfig, accessTokenCache);
//api = BoxAPIConnection.getAppUserConnection(USER_ID, boxConfig, accessTokenCache);

BoxUser.Info userInfo = BoxUser.getCurrentUser(api).getInfo();
System.out.format("Welcome, %s!\n\n", userInfo.getName());

}

}
```

Any assistance would be most appreciated.

Comment: Could you provide a valid `file.json` to be able to run the program

Comment: You should have `org.bouncycastle.operator.OperatorCreationException`, it is part of the `box-java-sdk` library. Maybe you need to clean and recompile. Can you find the class using your IDE?

Comment: I used box's admin screen to create the Json.  If I post it, I'm afraid everyone will have access to my box account until I reset the private key.  I can give you the json without the key.  I know you're trying to assist -- I'm just concerned about other people with nefarious intents.  I will look for the OperatorCreationException.

Comment: I managed to make a valid JSON format to try, but I get a NullPointerException, can't really reproduce your case :)

Comment: Can you actually do import `org.bouncycastle.operator.OperatorCreationException`?

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.  I have good news and bad news.  The good news is that you solved my problem (I think).  My jar file (it wasn't box, but a depndent bouncycastle jar) was corrupt! The bad news is that it's popping a new error.  I'll try troubleshooting a bit before I post it as an issue. Thank you so much!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Bentaye actually provided the answer.  One of my jars was corrupt.